# Use "setInterval()" a dynamic number of times, and tell when "clearInterval()" has been called for all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, setinterval

For node.js, I want to check for a new state every 10 seconds. This new state will exist different systems, and there could be 1 to 4 of these systems. The new state will eventually exist on all of the systems, but they will happen at different times, and once they have all updated I want to compare the results.

A broad overview would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < systems.length; i++)
{
    var interval = setInterval(function() { checkForUpdate(system[i].location); }, 10000);
}

function checkForUpdate(location)
{
    // Some code here to check if the state is updated
    if (stateUpdated)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. Since I don't know how many intervals I'll have to set, it is difficult to call clearInterval and pass the name (since I don't want to dynamically create variable names). Can I pass the 'interval' var to checkForUpdate so that each checkForUpdate will only clear their own interval?
2. How can I check to see if all of the intervals are cleared? My first thought is to create a variable that keeps track of the number of intervals cleared. Then set *another* setInterval that checks every 10 seconds to see if all intervals have been cleared, and do my final comparison of all the results once the number of intervals cleared == systems.length. But if there is a more elegant way without essentially setting another setInterval, that would be preferred. Something like a listener?

Comment: It seems like you could probably structure this better. Maybe take it over to Code Review and ask for their opinion.

Comment: have a look at the closure of your `index` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you could store your intervals in an array similar to your systems, or you generate a name based on the system (e.g. using the location) and store it in an object.

Something like this:

```
intervals[system.location] = setInterval(...);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is helpful for my first part. I will create an array like:

var intervals = [];

and then add the interval variables based on the index of the for loop, and pass that index to my function.

But for the second question, is there an elegant way to check that each interval has been cleared? Or should I just loop over the whole array and see if they are set to 0 (if I set them to 0 when I clear them).

Comment: You could keep a cleared state within the intervals array along side the interval, and update it when it is cleared in checkForUpdate, then immediately check if all is cleared to call a function to run on the end. You don't need to make a loop this way, only the last interval to be cleared will call it.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(function_name, time)`

This is called when you need to call a function after each event that you want to occur in that set of time. When you clear that interval it simply sets the interval value to zero. It has wide use. Please make more clear.